# Laptop screen is not switching on after running SQL code

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, black-screen-of-death

I was trying to run an SQL code on Visual StudioCode when the screen suddenly froze. Soon it started turning red from the borders (see attached pic). Soon it began spreading throughout the whole screen, at which point, I panicked and pressed the power button.

When I restarted, the screen is completely black and its not showing anything. I think the system is otherwise functional because I can hear windows sounds from the speaker.

My laptop is asus g15(2021 model) with windows 11. And I don't know if the code I ran had anything to do with it

[Screen Before shutting off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sug3E.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First `SQL` code have nothing to do with the problem.

Second probably your video controller (or eventually display) is broken. If it's on replaceable module you can put another controller. If not you should replace entire motherboard (or laptop). If it's display is (more or less) easy replaceable in repair center.

Comment: Thank you. I will check with the technicians of asus. But does that picture of my laptop seem like a commonly occuring problem?

Comment: @DominicJoseph, check. And no, it's not common problem, but may occur, especially if the laptop overheat.

Comment: One more doubt. I usually donot shut down my lap. Its automatically goes to sleep. Does it make sense to shut down at the end of the day to avoid these issues?

Comment: @DominicJoseph, IMHO sleep mode can't be the reason of overheating. And it's personal custom, I want to have my desktop on the way I leave it going in bed. So I sleep it. If its about desktop with mechanical disk I prefer to activate and use hibernate.